# Not Able to pull genes due to file.fa error

Tags: file-formats

I've recently been pulling TLR genes for different species and keep running across an error called file.fa whenever I start pulling them. Whenever I pull the first gene it's fine and makes the file.fa but when I pull the second gene (TLR4) it comes up with a file.fa error and deleted the previous file.fa
made from when I pulled the first gene. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

```
['NP_001273862', 'XP_006138208', 'XP_006138164', 'XP_014427015', 'XP_014429739']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blastp.py", line 104, in <module>
    SeqIO.write(record, "file.fa", 'fasta')
  File "/home/dylan_w190/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/__init__.py", line 522, in write
    with as_handle(handle, "w") as fp:
  File "/home/dylan_w190/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/home/dylan_w190/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Bio/File.py", line 72, in as_handle
    with open(handleish, mode, **kwargs) as fp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.fa'
```

Comment: Can U plz provide enough detail for me to try to reproduce the error?

Comment: Hi there, you seem to be new to this forum. It is good practice to provide full code to actually reproduce this error. Otherwise your question will quickly get closed. Right now we neither know about your input files, not the code you used and whether this is a tool or custom script. Please add all that.
This here should be the starting point to investigate:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.fa'`

Comment: Show your code please- the error is slightly counterintuitive to me since *writing* to a file should not lead to `FileNotFoundError`